# Environment variable ANDROID HOME not defined [Windows 10][Can't find SDK in installation folder]

Tags: android, cmd, sdk, windows-10, environment-variables

So, I tried setting the ANDROID_HOME through the Environment Variables but for some reason I can't find android-sdk while browsing through my directory where Android is installed.

I tried echoing for ANDROID_HOME in cmd and no positive results either.

The installation of Android Studio is in here:

> C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio

I've read through many of the guides for Windows for installing this stuff, but without this android-sdk file which every one of them mention it's a bit hard to do..

TL;DR: Where do I find android-sdk in my installation folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my Windows 10 it is found under

> C:\Users\my_user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

Maybe that is the place where it installed on your machine as well.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried echoing for ANDROID_HOME in cmd and no positive results either.

You cannot echo `ANDROID_HOME` because it does not add to Environment Variables. You should set it yourself in Environment Variables Window.

You can refer how to set `ANDROID_HOME` in this link: http://www.automationtestinghub.com/setup-android-environment-variables/

> I've read through many of the guides for Windows for installing this stuff, but without this android-sdk file which every one of them mention it's a bit hard to do..

When running setup android studio, if you don't change the path of Android SDk, in default the Android SDK is installed in `C:\Users\{UserName}\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\`.